# Passing a Vec into a function by reference

Tags: rust

I'm having some trouble passing a `Vec<u64>` into a function without moving it. I have a function `find_factors(mut n: u64, mut fctrs: Vec<u64>)` and I am currently calling from main like so:

```
fn main() {
    let mut primeFactors: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    find_factors(1134 as u64, primeFactors);
}
```

I'm forced right now to loop through and print out my vector in the `find_factors` function because I'm not sure how to pass the `Vec<u64>` by reference instead of moving it. How could I accomplish this? Example of what I want to do:

```
fn main() {
    let mut primeFactors: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    find_factors(1134 as u64, primeFactors);

    //for ....
        //print vector in main!
}
```

Comment: The preferred naming style, by the way, is `prime_factors`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you don't need to add or remove elements from the vector, use slice (`&[T]`) or mutable slice (`&mut [T]`):

```
fn find_factors(n: u64, prime_factors: &mut [u64]) { ... }

let mut prime_factors: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
find_factors(1134 as u64, prime_factors.as_mut_slice());
```

Immutable slices allow you to read elements or create subslices; mutable slices additionally allow to modify elements. But slices cannot grow - they are just a view into some vector.

It looks like you need to append new elements to the vector. You won't be able to do it using slice, as I said; you need to pass the vector itself using mutable reference:

```
fn find_factors(n: u64, prime_factors: &mut Vec<u64>) {
    // here you can call e.g. prime_factors.push(...)
}

let mut prime_factors: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
find_factors(1134 as u64, &mut prime_factors);
```

Comment: Trying to learn rust, I have a question with regards to your last sample: Wouldn't it be better/more idiomatic to pass the Vec by value and return it, without the & ? As the Vec allocates its data on the heap, it should itself be very small right?

Comment: @Tomas you're absolutely correct in that passing a `Vec` by value is very cheap - it consists of three pointer-sized values. However, I don't think that passing it by value here would be idiomatic. After all, passing it by mutable reference is strictly more general: if you have a `Vec<T>` by value, you can always create a `&mut Vec<T>` out of it, but if you only have `&mut Vec<T>`, you won't be able to "extract" `Vec<T>` from it easily.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Assuming I need to push to the referenced vector, how would I go for? I also see this question is slightly old, the latest version of Rust?

Answer (score 1):

Use `primeFactors.as_slice()` (or `primeFactors.as_mut_slice()` if you want to modify the contents of the vector in place) to pass a vector as a borrowed pointer.

Change your function to accept a borrowed slice of type `&[T]`.

Answer (score -2):

might be wrong but normally i just slap a .clone() at the end when im passing something into a function

Comment: Might not be a good idea, especially if the thing that you are passing is extremely large, because it creates a new variable on the stack that points to a newly copied value on the heap. For example, if a string takes up 100mb (quite contrived, but you get the point), calling `.clone()` will create a new copy, allocation an extra 100mb on the heap, which takes up a lot of space and also takes a fair bit of time as well.